# C++ custom exception message not displaying

Tags: c++, c++11, exception

I am trying to create a custom exception class, throw it, and display the error message, but I am doing something wrong, causing the exception to not get thrown and the message to not get printed.

Here's the exception class:

```
class UnbalancedParenthesesException : public std::exception {
  int line_number {0};
public:
  UnbalancedParenthesesException(int line_number) :
    line_number { line_number }
    {}

  virtual const char* what() const throw() {
    std::string exception_message =
      "Papentheses imbalance at line " + std::to_string(line_number) + "\n";

    return exception_message.c_str();
  }
};
```

I am trying to`try`/`throw`/`catch` as follows:

```
void handle_closed_paren(int line_number) {
  try { 
    if (definitely_unbalanced()) {
      throw UnbalancedParenthesesException(line_number);
    }
  } catch (const UnbalancedParenthesesException& e) {
      std::out << e.what() << "\n";
}
```

There is nothing pertinent to this error in the console.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `return exception_message.c_str();` returns the address of a local stack variable which will get destroyed on the return.

Comment: @RichardCritten: Answers go below thanks

Comment: Thanks, Richard. That is indeed the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your program has undefined behaviour as you are returning the result of `c_str()` on a `std::string` that goes out of scope. Anything could happen.

Beyond that, if you're not seeing an exception then one was not thrown, probably because the result of `definitely_unbalanced()` is falsey.

Step through your program using your debugger.

Comment: Thanks, that is the problem. I should be returning a `char*`, not a local `string`.

Comment: @progfan: Well, no, that doesn't sound like a fix. Who creates the thing it points to? Who destroys it? I recommend keeping the `std::string` as a member of the exception object (building it in the constructor) then you can safely return its `c_str()`.

Comment: You are right. It becomes messy this way. I'll build the `string` in the constructor.

Answer (score 3):

Your `what()` method is creating a local `std::string` variable and then returning a pointer to its internal data, which will be left dangling when the `std::string` goes out of scope and is destroyed when `what()` exits.

You need to store your error message in a `std::string` that is a member of the class so it does not go out of scope prematurely. Fortunately, `std::exception` already has an internal `std::string` for that purpose.  So, instead of formatting the error message in `what()` itself, you should format it in your derived constructor and pass it to the base class constructor, letting the base `what()` method return it as-is:

```
class UnbalancedParenthesesException : public std::exception
{
    int mLineNumber;
public:
    UnbalancedParenthesesException(int line_number) : std::exception("Parentheses imbalance at line " + std::to_string(line_number)), mLineNumber(line_number) {}

    // optional, if the catcher needs access to the value
    int lineNumber() const { return mLineNumber; }
};
```

Comment: Thanks, I like this solution. I didn't know I could construct like you do here.